# How to add time to a date variable in linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

tried this but failed

```
now=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
past=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d "${now} -5minutes")
echo $past
```

result:

```
date: invalid date ‘20200120175610 -5minutes’
```

TT

Comment: Works for me. What's the output of  ``date --version``?

Comment: @muru it is `date (GNU coreutils) 8.25`

Comment: What is the purpose of 'now'? That's the default without -d anyway. Try: date -d '5 mins ago'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems GNU date cannot parse timestamps in that format. It takes the leading portion to be a year:

```
% date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20200120175610 --debug
date: parsed number part: (Y-M-D) 2020012017-56-10
date: input timezone: system default
date: warning: using midnight as starting time: 00:00:00
date: error: invalid date/time value:
date:     user provided time: '(Y-M-D) 2020012017-56-10 00:00:00'
date:        normalized time: '(Y-M-D) 2020012021-08-10 00:00:00'
date:                                  ---- --
date:      possible reasons:
date:        numeric values overflow;
date:        missing timezone
date: invalid date ‘20200120175610’
```

If it doesn't error out, then it probably didn't overflow, but it's still not doing what you'd expect:

```
% date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d "20200120181002 -5minutes" --debug
date: parsed hybrid part: -5 minutes
date: input timezone: system default
date: warning: using midnight as starting time: 00:00:00
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2020012018-10-02 00:00:00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2020012018-10-02 00:00:00' = 63745360147926000 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+0 hours, -5 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 63745360147925700 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 63745360147925700.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2020012018-10-01 14:55:00 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2020012018-10-01 23:55:00 (UTC+09)
20200120181001235500
```

Use a different timestamp format. I suggest using ISO-8601, and reformatting as needed when outputing:

```
% now=$(date --iso-8601=seconds)
% past=$(date -d "$now - 5 minutes" --iso-8601=seconds)
% printf "%s\n" "$now" "$past"
2020-01-20T18:29:50+09:00
2020-01-20T18:24:50+09:00
% date -d "$past" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20200120182450
```

Comment: you are perfect

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, using `date (GNU coreutils) 8.26`.

```
$ date -d "5 minutes ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20200120101533
```

Answer (score -1):

It might work like this.

```
past=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d ${now} -d "-5minutes")
```

Comment: didn't use $now

Comment: This is not a correct answer. The second `-d` will override the first, so this solution is actually working by accident. It's actually correct to just specify `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d "-5minutes"`, since `now` is implied.